# Kie (Drools) + Spring + Camel + Excel decision table

Tags: excel, spring, drools

I currently have working excel decision tables being read into camel routes with following libraries:

- Drools 5.6.0.final
- Camel 2.14.0
- Spring-boot 1.0.2
- JDK 7

We are in process of upgrading spring-boot to 1.1.5 and after upgrade the drools decision table compilation started to crash , even with 2 GB of permGen space assigned.

It seems new spring-boot version causes some sort of classloader loop that eats all the PerGem it can find.

If we use JDK8, problem "goes away", but start up process eats 1,6GB of memory during drools decision table compilation.

I tried upgrading drools to 6.1.0 (KIE), but then i am not able to use excel-based decision tables anymore as there seems not to be any way to configure Spring/Camel/Drools beans anymore. Or at least http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch.kie.spring.html#d0e12957 doesn't provide any clues on how to achieve this.

Does anyone know of a way to either make drools 5.6.0 work more efficiently under JDK 7 OR how to allow excel decision tables under JDK 8 with Drools/Kie 6+?

Exception stacktrace on JDK 7 permGen error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excelDTABLE_KBase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at my.domain.Application.main(Application.java:54)

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:624)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:254)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:237)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.wire(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:434)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.wire(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:429)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.onBeforeExecute(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:257)
    at org.drools.rule.DialectRuntimeRegistry.onBeforeExecute(DialectRuntimeRegistry.java:139)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.reloadAll(PackageBuilder.java:1202)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:951)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:938)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDecisionTable(PackageBuilder.java:451)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:715)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:51)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:40)
    at org.drools.container.spring.beans.KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.afterPropertiesSet(KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
```

Comment: It's possible that you have overstrained decision tables. (It has happened before.) Can you provide some statistics about the number of lines (= rules) resulting from the decisions tables? Even better, provide the number of differente tables, and the number of rows and columns for each table.

Comment: Problematic excel contains one rule with 460, 13 condition columns and one action column. It is bi-lingual, so I tried removing one language conditions but PermGen space error is still there so even at 230 lines the rule seems to be too complex.

Comment: in total i have 38 decision table files that are compiled into spring / camel beans during startup, and always the same (2nd biggest by byte size) file is the cause of the PermGen space error

Comment: Each line produces one rule which results in one static Java class. The number of files doesn't matter, nor does the number of columns if it is as small as you wrote. - You may have to look for other ways of producing your rules.

Comment: Problem is related to spring-boot and how + Drools do class loading for drool's objects when compiling decision tables into classes. As everything works fine with Spring-boot 1.0.2. but with spring-boot 1.1.5 PermGen error happens.

Answer (score 1):

solution provided is for drool decision table using kie using spring boot

[refference for drool table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meNAu.png) FYI-do mindful that object shared across condition must have merged cells across those conditons

```
@Configuration
public class DroolConfig {

    private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    private KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem() throws IOException {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        String xls[] = new String[] {"wallet.xls","offer.xls"}; // path to file
        for(int i=0 ; i< xls.length; i++) {
            kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(xls[i]));
        }
        return kieFileSystem;

    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer getKieContainer() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Container created...");
        getKieRepository();
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(getKieFileSystem());
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        return kContainer;

    }

    private void getKieRepository() {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
            public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
                return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public KieSession getKieSession() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("session created...");
        return getKieContainer().newKieSession();

    }

}
```

```
@RestController
public class MegaOfferController {
    @Autowired
    private KieSession session;

    @PostMapping("/order")
    public Order orderNow(@RequestBody Order order) {
        session.insert(order);
        session.fireAllRules();
        return order;
    }
```

```
<properties>
        <drools.version>6.4.0.Final</drools.version>
</properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
     <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
     <version>${drools.version}</version>
   </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
         </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```